# Send an email using PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, email, frontend

When I enter information to submit, it never goes through. I get the error under my code validation. 
How would anyone approach this kind of problem?

```
      <?php

        $EmailTo = "cccxx@hotmail.com";
        $Subject = "Site Contact";
        $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
        $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
        $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

        // Email body text
        $Body = " ";
        $Body .= "Name: "; 
        $Body .= $Name;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Email: ";
        $Body .= $Email;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Message: ";
        $Body .= $Message;
        $Body .= "\n";

        // send email 
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$Email>");

        if ($_POST['submit']) {
            if ($Name != '' && $Email != '' && $Message != '') {               
                if ($success) { 
                  echo '<p class="bg-success" style="padding:15px 10px;">Your message has been sent!</p>'; 
              } else { 
                  echo '<p class="bg-danger" style="padding:15px 10px;">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
              }
            } else {
                echo '<p class="bg-danger" style="padding:15px 10px;">You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: For one thing, there is not a `$_POST['submit']` for a submit button.

Comment: use isset($_POST['submit'])

Comment: What's the error? after click on submit?

Answer (score 2):

Basic steps to bedug your script...

1. Enable error reporting in your script. (add this to the beginning of
   your script)

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   ```
2. In your case you may have to check the $_POST variable in the
   script.

   ```
   echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";
   ```
3. Also make sure that you have set method="post" in your form tag